# Python Pandas Dataframe Multiplying 2 columns results replicated values of column A

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

OK I am trying something I think should be very simple but it's doesn't seem to be working.

I have a Panda Dataframe which includes many columns.  There are 2 which I want to multiply but instead of the resulting new column displaying the result of multiplying the two values, it shows the value in column A the number of times that is in column B

Example:

```
dataframe['totalcost'] = dataframe['orderedQuantity.amount'].mul(dataframe['netCost.amount'])
```

Also tried this:

```
dataframe['totalcost'] = dataframe['orderedQuantity.amount'] * dataframe['netCost.amount']
```

netCost.amount = 12

orderedQuantity.amount = 3

totalcost results in 121212 instead of 36

What am I missing?

Comment: You have strings, convert to numeric first

Comment: I knew I was missing something simple. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the values in `orderedQuantity` are string/object type. Cast to numeric to resolve the issue

```
dataframe['totalcost'] = dataframe['orderedQuantity.amount'].mul(dataframe['netCost.amount'].astype(float))
```

Comment: I think it's the other way around: `dataframe['orderedQuantity.amount'].mul(dataframe['netCost.amount'].astype(float))`?

Comment: Nope its not `'12' * 3 = '121212'` @Corralien

Comment: Sure? **totalcost results in 121212 instead of 36**

Comment: gotcha i thought orderedQuantity.amount  was 12